# How to run Angular JS on after page load rendered html?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm developing asp.net mvc a project with angular js.

I'm working on tabs and install related partial view after click event.

I am sending with partial view html of the json to main page but angular codes doesn't work on the page

What can i do?

[Sample Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/7yqrjdkk/7/)

html:

```
<div ng-app="MyAppS">
<div ng-controller="AnaTest">
    <button id="btn1" ng-click="btn1Click()">click</button>
</div>
<div id="m_area">
</div>
<br />{{ 'Hello Angular' }}</div>
```

javascript:

```
var m_app = angular.module('MyAppS', []);

function AnaTest($scope) {
    $scope.btn1Click = function () {
    var runtimeBtn = angular.element("<button ng-click=\"btn2Click()\">Help Me!        </button>");
    $('#m_area').html(runtimeBtn);
};

$scope.btn2Click = function(){
    debugger;
    alert('Why can not show?!');
    };
};
```

m_app.controller('AnaTest', AnaTest);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it:

```
var runtimeBtn = $compile(angular.element("<button ng-click=\"btn2Click()\">Help Me!</button>"))($scope);
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/7yqrjdkk/8/

---

However, a more "Angular" way to do it would be putting it under the same controller/scope and simply using `ng-show`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7yqrjdkk/9/

Comment: You're welcome! :) Consider this a more "Angular" way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/7yqrjdkk/9/